# RequestScoped JSF CDI bean with Bootstrap modal

Tags: jsf, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-3, cdi

I am using JSF 2.0 with a Bootstrap 3 framework. Everything seems to be working fine, but I get problems when I want to populate forms in a Bootstrap modal from a RequestScoped CDI bean. It seems to me, after debugging, that the bean is instantiated when the page the modal is in loads, and not when the modal is opened. So, when I then open the modal, the bean does not exist anymore. Here is some of my code:

**This is where I open the modal**

```
<li><a href="#editModal" data-toggle="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> &nbsp;Rediger bruker</a></li>
```

**This is the modal content, which is on the same page. farmer is the name of bean**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Endre bruker</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="well">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#profile" class="" data-toggle="tab">Profil</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#password" class="" data-toggle="tab">Passord</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#reference" class="" data-toggle="tab">Referanseperson</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="profile">
                            <h:form class="form-horizontal form-group">
                                <fieldset>
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <h:outputText id="email" class="form-control" value="#{farmer.theFarmer.email}"/>
```

Is there any way to prevent the bean from constructing when the page is loaded, but instead when the actual form is rendered?

Looked around on the internet for a long time, but I cannot seem to find anything that helps me.

Comment: No, this isn't possible.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Is there any other way to get around this? I know I've used ViewScopes before, but with CDI I have to use ConversationScope instead. Would it be possible to start a conversation when I open the modal? I don't really know how I would do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the component lazily loaded, so that the content is retrieved on a new HTTP request.  Assuming you use something like primefaces, you can use p:fragment.  If you use RichFaces you can use a rich:outputPanel.  Just make sure both of these are set to be rerendered.

You can also use something low level like a JSF panelGrid, and rerender that based on an AJAX call.

Comment: If I use the option with the JSF panelGrid, I would put this AJAX call in the link where I open the modal right? And also I guess I would have to use something else than the <a> tag?

Comment: Yes, you would need to call some javascript that interacted with JSF in the a tag.  Yes, basically wrap the entire modal in a JSF tag to do this.